# Emberjs 2.11.0 strange RSVP behaviour

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I've looked at release notes but can't find anything that mentions changes to how RSVPs work, but is there a reason this isn't working?

On the route, a very simple model:

```
  model() {
    return RSVP.hash({
      posts: get(this, 'store').findAll('post')
    });
  }
```

and in the template:

```
{{#each posts as |post|}}
  {{post.title}}
{{/each}}
```

Returns nothing, however if I use a standard model call such as

```
  model() {
    return get(this, 'store').findAll('post');
  }
```

with

```
{{#each model as |post|}}
  {{post.title}}
{{/each}}
```

It works as expected. I've done many many apps on previous 2.9.0 and never had a problem with this...

Little confused!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RSVP.hash` returns an object where each key holds a resolved value from a promise.

In your case this means that the `model` will be `{ posts: ... }` so you're just missing a `.posts` property chain call:

route:

```
model() {
  return RSVP.hash({
    posts: get(this, 'store').findAll('post')
  });
}
```

template:

```
{{#each model.posts as |post|}}
  {{post.title}}
{{/each}}
```

---

If you want to use this template

```
{{#each posts as |post|}}
  {{post.title}}
{{/each}}
```

You can set `posts` in `setupController`:

```
model() {
  return RSVP.hash({
    posts: get(this, 'store').findAll('post')
  });
}

setupController(controller, model) {
  controller.set('posts', model.posts);
}
```

Comment: Oh I was forgetting to setup the controller!

Comment: @Peavers glad you got it working :)

Comment: While the `setupController` approach works, I find more idiomatic to avoid `RSVP.hash` and just use `{{each model as |post|}}` in the template, or if you really want to do `{{each posts as |post|}}`, define an alias in the controller: `posts: Ember.computed.alias('model')`